# Store date from loop in variable in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT body FROM comments");

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   $body .= $r['body'];
}
?>

<?php echo $body ?><br />
```

Can someone explain why it prints out all comments without no space? It prints out all my entries but they are all together. And the `<br />` only after the last comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the following to append a `<br />` after each comment:

```
$body .= $r['body'].'<br />';
```

Comment: thanks that works but i think i will have to use another approach i wanted to do this to make it easier for a designer